# How does BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization work, and how can you wrap it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

So I'm trying to understand how BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization works, and this basic toy example works as you'd expect, it just magically sends the collection update to the UI thread:

```
using DynamicData.Binding;
using DynamicData;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace testapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> List1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private static object lockObject = new object();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(List1, lockObject);

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //without EnableCollectionSynchronization this would just fail

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (lockObject) //it seems to work even without locking, but probably prudent to use it
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        List1.Add("test");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I thought that it would be much more convenient to wrap up all the locking and stuff into a wrapper class, so I wrote this:

```
public class ThreadedObservableCollection<T> : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public int Count => Collection.Count;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection;
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public ThreadedObservableCollection()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        Collection.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged;

        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Collection, _lockObj);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            Collection.Clear();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                return Collection[index];
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                Collection[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            Collection.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T value)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            return Collection.Remove(value);
        }
    }

    private void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

But testing it out I just get the standard "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread." exception. What's going on here? Why doesn't it work? How does EnableCollectionSynchronization actually operate in general?

Edit: Changing

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Collection, _lockObj);
```

to

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lockObj);
```

actually makes it work as expected! But how and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how and why?

Because `EnableCollectionSynchronization` enables the `CollectionView` that sits in between the source collection and the `ItemsControl` to participate in synchronized access. So you need to call it on the actual `INotifyCollectionChanged` that you bind to in the view.

`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Collection)` is not equal to `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this)`. In fact, `Collection` should be a private field of `ThreadedObservableCollection<T>` because it's an implementation detail. The view and WPF binds to an instance of `ThreadedObservableCollection<T>` and knows nothing about the internal `ObservableCollection<T>`.